# ReactDOM is not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dom

That`s my Index.js before changes(everithing was working):

```
import React from "react"
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import App  from './App'
import state from './components/Redux/State'
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

ReactDOM.render(<App state={state} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Then, I changed it to this:

```
import React from "react"
import App  from './App'
import state from './components/Redux/State'
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

ReactDOM.render(<App state={state} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

So, I had this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwRIa.png)

And now, after adding ReactDOM I have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGVBU.png)
Gradient on the background and that`s it

That`s my App.js code:

```
import React from "react"
import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar"
import Profile from "./components/Profile/Profile"
import Dialogs from "./components/Dialogs/Dialogs"
import Music from "./components/Music/Music"
import News from "./components/News/News"
import Settings from "./components/Settings/Settings"
import s from './css/App.module.css'
import b from './css/AppBlureBackground.module.scss'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"


const App = (props) => { 
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className={b.app_grideffect_wrap}>
                <div className={b.wrap}>
                    <div className={b.top_plane} ></div>
                    <div className={b.bottom_plane} ></div>
                </div>
                <div className={s.app__wraper}>
                    <Header />
                    <Navbar state={props.state} />
                    <div className={s.app__content_wrap}>
                        <div className={s.content__scroll_wrap}>
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile  posts={props.state.profilePage.posts} />} />
                                <Route path='/dialogs/*' element={<Dialogs state={props.state} />} />
                                <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
                                <Route path='/music' element={<Music />} />
                                <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
                            </Routes>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

}

export default App
```

So, I just started learning React and Redux and I`m trying to add Redux to my project

The question is - how can I fix this problem with ReactDOM?
How to add ReactDOM and Redux actually correctly to my project?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZccn.png)
And it`s no ERRORS in Terminal

I tryed to add Redux to my project, the first step is to add ReactDOM syntax and it`s failed.
i expected to add Redux but I got no render on my web site when i checked browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>Frend.Me</title>
</head>

<body onload="animatedCursor();">
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="animatedCursor.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does your HTML file look like?

Comment: There is no `/` route

Comment: @Konrad Thank you for your answer. what do you mean?

Comment: @moy2010 Thank you for your answer. I just added my HTML to the post

Comment: Try to start with the basics. Render a simple div from React before you bring the router and Redux. Advance one step at a time.

Comment: @moy2010 Yeah, I`ll start over all of my redux manipulation cause of it`s to many things to change there
Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing your app state in like this. This will only be a snapshot of the first value your Redux state ever had, never an updated value of what is actually there after the store changed. For that, you have to use `react-redux`.

Please follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts), you seem to be lacking a lot of basics here!